# How to make Nested Model Scope work in sidebar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, scope, sidebar

How can we make **layouts/_stats.html.erb** work in the sidebar, which shows on all pages:

```html
<b><center>Average</center></b>

<ul>
<li>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
  <% averaged.statsresults.each do |result| %>
        <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b") %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %>
        <b><%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %></b><% end %>
        <%= result.result_value %>
        <%= averaged.metric %>

</li>
</ul>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<b><center>Instance</center></b>

<ul>
  <% @instance_quantifieds.each do |instance| %>
  <% instance.statsresults.each do |result| %>
        <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b %d") %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(instance) do %>
        <b><%= raw instance.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %></b><% end %>
        <%= result.result_value %>
        <%= instance.metric %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

without getting this error: `undefined method "statsresults" for #<Quantified:0x007ff739b42728>` being generated by `<% averaged.statsresults.each do |result| %>`

Results belong to quantified and as you can see below I'm trying to **use scope to limit the multitude of potential `:results` to just the most up-to-date one**:

```html
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified

  scope :stats, -> do
   order("date_value").
   limit(1)
  end
end
```

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  has_many :results #correct
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Averaged') }
  scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'Instance') }
  validates :categories, :metric, presence: true
 acts_as_taggable

 CATEGORIES = ['Averaged', 'Instance']
end
```

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_todays_habits
  before_action :set_top_3_goals
  before_action :randomize_value
  before_action :set_stats
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def set_top_3_goals
    @top_3_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.top_3 if current_user
  end

  def randomize_value
    @sidebarvaluations = current_user.valuations.randomize if current_user
  end

  def set_stats
    @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
    @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
    @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
    @statsresults = current_user.results.stats
  end
```

**Thanks for the help** and if you have time I could also use help with another scope question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863999/how-to-automate-into-method

Comment: Which line of your view is failing - just for more context?

Comment: @patrick   <% averaged.statsresults.each do |result| %>

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how `statsresults` is a method of `Quantifieds`. `@statsresults` is just an instance set up in your application controller. Am I missing something?

Comment: It was my attempt at this sorry @patrick I'm still trying to get a grasp of it all. I want it to be a method for results so that only the most update result will show in the sidebar per quantified, but there could be as many quantifieds as the User makes. The method also has to be in the application controller because the sidebar will be shown on all pages. `averaged.results.each` works in the index so I was trying to make `averaged.statsresults.each` work in the sidebar to do the specific purpose outlined above.

Comment: Can you try moving the `averaged.statsresults.each` to its own block and just try `statsresults.each do |stat|` ? Also, you should put a an underscore in `statsresults` to make it `stats_results` for readability. Also your indentation makes it a bit hard to follow. Keep trying!

Comment: Thanks @patrick! I tried but no luck here. Would including `averaged.stats_results` be necessary though for rails to be able to differentiate between the results entered under averaged and those under instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72376/discussion-between-anthonygalli-com-and-patrick).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<b><center>Average</center></b>

<ul>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <li>
      <% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
        <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b") %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %>
          <b><%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %></b>
        <% end %>
        <%= result.result_value %>
        <%= result.metric %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

If this gets the desired result you can do the same thing for `@instanced_quantifieds`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because `date_value` & `result_value` follow under `:results` in the database.